# Zend_Action_Helper_Redirector with preDispatch() plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework

If i call $this->_helper->redirector('index'); the preDispatch won't be called is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirector will exit the code by default; by overriding this with `$this->_helper->redirector->setExit(false);` it will execute your code normally (with preDispatch ect).